# Non-stochastic or efficient way to find valid aspect ratio range for drawing a smaller rectangle with desired area size inside of a larger rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I have a large rectangle (of size B), in which I want to put a smaller rectangle of size A such that A <= B.

I need to get the range of possible aspect ratios for rectangles of size A that can be drawn within the rectangle of size B.

I can partly solve this problem stochastically (generating random width/height pairs for the area A and checking if the rectangle fits in B) in a while loop which makes the algorithm super inefficient in particular cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can put any aspect ratio there if image B is scale appropriately. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @fmw42, your claim is false. You cannot put any aspect ratio covering a fixed sized area (A) within a rectangular boundary. In the extreme case imagine A=B, the only aspect ratio that you can choose is equal to that of the outer rectangle's. Otherwise, your choices are capped by maximum width, height and the coverage area itself.

Comment: You did not say it needed to be filled. That was the missing information to make sense of your request and why I asked you to clarify.

Comment: I am sorry but have you read the text at all? It has been clearly stated in the title, in the first sentence, and in the second sentence while it is also implied (almost explicit) in the third sentence.